# How to create a footer

Tags: html, css, footer

[This is my header image, i want the same as footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58OsD.png) Instead of that google on the left, i need copyrights reserved in the footer part with the same padding in the header i.e 70px. and i have another issue i have created a submenu in about link which is not working properly. I need the same menu in the footer part as "dropup".

Here is my snippet

NOTE: **Please run in full window, while using snippet**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: #333;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#logo {
 width: 130px;
 height: 55px;
 margin: 5px 0 5px 70px;
}

nav {
 background-color: #222;
}

ul {
 float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
 width:;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #262626;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

/*jumbotron*/
.content {
 padding: 20px 0 0;
 background-color: #eee;
 text-align: center;
 height: 150px;
}

.heading {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

/*default props for img gallery*/
.imggal {
 display: inline-flex;
}


/*row1 img*/
.col1 #tech {
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 40px;
}

/*default column props on rows*/
.col1,.col2 {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

/*default props for all images except row1 */
.img {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 margin: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
}

.imgthumbnail {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
}

/*row3 img's*/
.r3c1, .r3c2 {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}

/*to stop overflowing on the img*/
.r2imgtxt {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.r3imgtxt {
 text-align: center;
}

footer {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #222;
 padding: 10px 0;
 color: #fff;
 bottom: 0;
}

footer nav {
 float: right;
}

footer nav ul {
 margin:20px 0;
}

footer nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
 <title>A sample web page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <nav>
   <img id="logo" src="images/google_logo.png" alt="google logo">
   <ul class="headermenu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a> 
         <ul class="headersub">
           <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
 
  <!-- content -->
  <div class="content">
   <h1 class="heading">Welcome to Google</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- body -->
  <div class="imggal">
   <div class="col1">
    <img id="tech" src="images/tech.png" alt="technology">
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- EOF row1 -->

  <!-- row2 -->
  <div class="imggal">
   <div class="col1">
    <img class="img r2c1" src="images/www.png" alt="earth as www">
     <div class="r2imgtxt">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
     </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <img class="img r2c2" src="images/technology.png" alt="technology">
     <div class="r2imgtxt">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
     </div> 
   </div>
  </div> <!-- EOF row2 -->
 
  <!-- row3 -->
  <div class="imggal">
   <div class="col1">
    <div class="imgthumbnail">
     <img class="r3c1" src="images/apple.png" alt="apple logo"> 
    </div>
    <div class="r3imgtxt">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div> <!-- EOF col1row3 --> 
   <div class="col2">
    <div class="imgthumbnail">
     <img class="r3c2" src="images/computer.png" alt="computer">
    </div>
    <div class="r3imgtxt">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div> <!-- EOF col2row3 -->
  </div> <!-- EOF row3 -->
  <!-- EOF body -->

  <footer>
   <nav>
    <p id="copyrights">&copy; Copyrights Reserved. Google Inc.</p>
    <ul id="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a> 
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
  </footer> <!-- EOF footermenu -->
 </div> <!-- EOF container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple mod:

```
footer nav {
    float: none;
}

nav ul {
    float: none;
}
nav li:hover ul {
    bottom: 25px;
}
ul.headersub li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i have some problem in dropdown menu in the header please consider that and then reply